# Is there any module dependency definition for linux kernel module in source code level?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, dependencies, linux-device-driver

I know that we can check the Linux kernel module dependency at runtime with the lsmod or modprobe command.
But what if we only have the kernel code, is there a way to check the kernel module's dependency, or is there any dependency definition in the kernel source code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MODULE_DEPEND() macro might help you here

Comment: I tried to grep the string "MODULE_DEPEND" in the Linux kernel source folder, but cannot find any appearance of this string, even back to the v4.8. Can you specify where is this macro definition? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the **Kconfig** entry for the driver. Dependency to external modules, subsystem is specified as

- [depends on](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/kbuild/kconfig-language.txt#L106) (dependencies)
- [select](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/kbuild/kconfig-language.txt#L119) (reverse dependencies)

You can find more details in [Documentation/kbuild/kconfig-language.txt](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/kbuild/kconfig-language.txt)

For example, if `CONFIG_MY_DRIVER` depends on `I2C`, you can specify this as `depends on` in `Kconfig`. This means, if `I2C` is not selected in menuconfig, `MY_DRIVER` will not show up in menuconfig entry.

Opposite to which, when you use `select`, `I2C` is automatically selected when selecting `MY_DRIVER`.